# Update ArrayAdapter depending on spinner item selection

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have activity where user can select some products categories on spinners. Since I have 14 categories in order to avoid `ScrollView` overhead user can dynamically add spinners (up to 14) to  `ScrollView`. My goal is to avoid duplicates in selected items. For instance: if user selects category `A`, it must be removed from `ArrayAdapter` and not available for selection and if user decides to change category `A` to `B`, `A` must be available again. What can a possible solution?

**UPDATE**
I had following idea

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Create temporary array list
            ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();
           //Go trough all spinners and add selected items to temp array list
            for(int i =1001; i<categorySpinnerId-1; i++){
                tempArray.add(((Spinner)findViewById(i)).getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
            //Remove from original array list items of temp array list
            categoryArrayList.removeAll(tempArray);
            categorySpinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

But in this case I received following problem. For instance user added 5 spinners. First spinners has all 14 options, second 13 (excluding first selection), third 12(excluding first and second selection) and so on. Newly created spinner selection does not affect previous spinners option list.

Comment: what you tried for this. Provide your code snippet..

Answer (score 0):

Use a dynamic Array in which you store all your spinner entries without the selected one.

Example:

Full array: `A, B, C, D, E`

Let's say user picks `B`

So you do something like

```
for (String a : originalArray) {
    if (!a.equals("B")) {
        tempArray.add(a);
    }
}
```

Then set `tempArray` to the spinner view adapter.

Answer (score 0):

use HashSet it will not allow duplicates:
`HashSet h=new HashSet();
        h.add("a");
        h.add("a");
        h.add("b");
        h.add("c");

```
    System.out.println(" sdsadsd="+h); `
```

check this example

[link1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashset_class.htm)

[link2](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashset-class-in-java-with-example/)

Comment: please attach example link